# perl : String extraction based on pattern match

Tags: string, perl, pattern-matching

A file FILE1 has several thousands of lines with a terminating pattern _Pattern1.

A second file too has several thousands of lines with the same terminating pattern _Pattern1.

I must now:

- Read FILE1 line by line
- Find out if the line has any string terminating with _Pattern1
- Extract the string and store it into a variable
- Open FILE2 and read it line by line
- Find out if the line just read from FILE2 contains the string stored in the variable above

How is this to be done in perl?

EDIT2:

Allright, with a bit of googling and referring to the links enlisted below, I solved my problem. 
Here is the code snippet.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $OriginalHeader=$ARGV[0]; ## Source file
my $GeneratedHeader=$ARGV[1];## File to compare against
my $DeltaHeader=$ARGV[2];    ## File to store misses

my $MatchingPattern="_Pos";
my $FoundPattern;

open FILE1, $OriginalHeader or die $!;
open FILE2, $GeneratedHeader or die $!;
open (FILE3, ">$DeltaHeader") or die $!;

my $lineFromOriginalHeader;
my $lineFromGeneratedHeader;
my $TotalMacrosExamined = 0;
my $TotalMacrosMissed = 0;

while($lineFromOriginalHeader=<FILE1>)
{
 if($lineFromOriginalHeader =~ /$MatchingPattern/)
  {
    my $index = index($lineFromOriginalHeader,$MatchingPattern);

    my $BackIndex = $index;
    my $BackIndexStart = $index;

    $BackIndex = $BackIndex - 1;

    ## Use this while loop to extract the substring. 
    while (1)
    {
      my $ExtractedChar = substr($lineFromOriginalHeader,$BackIndex,1);
      if ($ExtractedChar =~ / /)
      {
        $FoundPattern = substr($lineFromOriginalHeader,$BackIndex + 1,$BackIndexStart + 3 - 
                                                                                $BackIndex); 
        print "Identified $FoundPattern \n";
        $TotalMacrosExamined = $TotalMacrosExamined + 1;
        ##Skip the next line
        $lineFromOriginalHeader = <FILE1>;
        last;       
      }
     else
     {
      $BackIndex = $BackIndex - 1;
     }

   } ##while(1)

 ## We now look for $FoundPattern in FILE2
 while ($lineFromGeneratedHeader = <FILE2>)
 {
  if (index($lineFromGeneratedHeader,$FoundPattern)!= -1)
   {
     ##Pattern found. Reset file pointer and break out of while loop
     seek FILE2,0,0;
     last;
   }
   else
   {
     if (eof(FILE2) == 1)
      {         
        print FILE3 "Generated header misses $FoundPattern\n";
        $TotalMacrosMissed = $TotalMacrosMissed + 1;
        seek FILE2,0,0; 
        last;       
      }
   }
} ##while(1)

}
else
{
  ##NOP
}
} ##while (linefromoriginalheader)

close FILE1;
close FILE2;
close FILE3;
print "Total number of bitfields examined = $TotalMacrosExamined\n";
print "Number of macros obsolete = $TotalMacrosMissed\n";
```

Comment: You outlined the steps pretty well.  Are you new to Perl, or to programming regardless of the language? If you're just new to Perl, almost everything you describe is found in http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html  Once you have some code to show we can help you with the tricky parts.

Comment: There is more than one way to do it, here's one: `$ perl -ne'exec q;perl;, "-ne", q $print (/\Q$.$1.q;/?"$. YES":$. .q\; NO\;);, "file2" if m;^(.*)_pat1;' file1` This should do the trick, minus a few gotchas. I have no idea if this compiles, but I like the look of it. Note the use of `exec` as a loop terminator. And I don't even *have* to assign to a single variable :-) There are, of course easier ways — [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: When using regexes, we can declare *capturing groups* by enclosing everything we want to be captured with parens. Your regex will then look like `/($MatchingPattern)/`. The content of the group will be in the special variable `$1` until you do another regex match. [Perl's regexp tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Extracting-matches) might come in handy when learning perl regexes.

Comment: I am not new to programming. Its just that i have barely used perl before. Perl surely is fun!

Comment: [It's OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), but please share your knowledge Q&A-style by posting your answer as an actual answer, but _not_ within your question. This allows the answer to be voted/accepted and helps us to keep the "Unanswered" list more clear. Thank you.

Comment: Also, why are we "skipping the next line"? Is this part of your design spec?\

Comment: Dear Joel, Yes this is necessary. I have edited my solution with necessary clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having programmed in C all my life, I googled usage of the perl constructs below and wrote a C like program. This works flawlessly for me. :-)

Edit : This is to clarify why I must skip a line in the algo below. The pattern which is retrieved and later searched for in the second file occurs on two consecutive lines. It therefore suffices that its first occurence is reliably detected. Also a nitpick, It is always guaranteed that the substring containing the pattern is always the second substring on the line.

e.g #define Something_Pos (Some Value)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $OriginalHeader=$ARGV[0];
my $GeneratedHeader=$ARGV[1];
my $DeltaHeader=$ARGV[2];

my $MatchingPattern="_Pos";
my $FoundPattern;

open FILE1, $OriginalHeader or die $!;
open FILE2, $GeneratedHeader or die $!;
open (FILE3, ">$DeltaHeader") or die $!;

my $lineFromOriginalHeader;
my $lineFromGeneratedHeader;
my $TotalMacrosExamined = 0;
my $TotalMacrosMissed = 0;

while($lineFromOriginalHeader=<FILE1>)
{
 if($lineFromOriginalHeader =~ /$MatchingPattern/)
 {
  my $index = index($lineFromOriginalHeader,$MatchingPattern);

  my $BackIndex = $index;
  my $BackIndexStart = $index;

  $BackIndex = $BackIndex - 1;

  ## Use this while loop to extract the substring. 
  while (1)
  {
   my $ExtractedChar = substr($lineFromOriginalHeader,$BackIndex,1);
   if ($ExtractedChar =~ / /)
    {
     $FoundPattern = substr($lineFromOriginalHeader,$BackIndex + 1,$BackIndexStart + 3 - 
                                                                                $BackIndex); 
     print "Identified $FoundPattern \n";
     $TotalMacrosExamined = $TotalMacrosExamined + 1;
     ##Skip the next line
     $lineFromOriginalHeader = <FILE1>;
     last;       
    }
   else
    {
     $BackIndex = $BackIndex - 1;
    }

} ##while(1)

 ## We now look for $FoundPattern in FILE2
while ($lineFromGeneratedHeader = <FILE2>)
{
 ##print "Read the following line from FILE2: $lineFromGeneratedHeader\n";

  if (index($lineFromGeneratedHeader,$FoundPattern)!= -1)
   {
     ##Pattern found. Close the file and break out of while loop
     seek FILE2,0,0;
     last;
   }
   else
   {
     if (eof(FILE2) == 1)
      {         
        print FILE3 "Generated header misses $FoundPattern\n";
        $TotalMacrosMissed = $TotalMacrosMissed + 1;
        seek FILE2,0,0; 
        last;       
      }
   }
 } ##while(1)

}
else
{

}
} ##while (linefromoriginalheader)

close FILE1;
close FILE2;
close FILE3;
print "Total number of bitfields examined = $TotalMacrosExamined\n";
print "Number of macros obsolete = $TotalMacrosMissed\n";
```

Comment: This code seems like it would work, however I have added an answer which takes this code and makes it a little more Perlish. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12012931/468327

Answer (score 0):

Just a first cut at making your code more Perly. Actually plenty more could be done, including `$some_var` is usually used vs `$SomeVar` in Perl, but I didn't get that far.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($OriginalHeader, $GeneratedHeader, $DeltaHeader) = @ARGV;
my $MatchingPattern=qr/(\S*_Pos)/; # all non-whitespace terminated by _Pos

open my $file1, '<', $OriginalHeader  or die $!;
open my $file2, '<', $GeneratedHeader or die $!;
open my $file3, '>', $DeltaHeader     or die $!;

my $TotalMacrosExamined = 0;
my $TotalMacrosMissed = 0;

while(my $lineFromOriginalHeader=<$file1>) {
  next unless $lineFromOriginalHeader =~ $MatchingPattern;
  my $FoundPattern = $1; # matched string

  print "Identified $FoundPattern \n";
  $TotalMacrosExamined++;

  ##Skip the next line
  <$file1>;

  ## We now look for $FoundPattern in FILE2
  my $match_found = 0;
  while (my $lineFromGeneratedHeader = <$file2>) {
    if (index($lineFromGeneratedHeader,$FoundPattern)!= -1) {
      ##Pattern found. Close the file and break out of while loop
      $match_found++;
      last;
    } 
  }

  unless ($match_found) {
    print $file3 "Generated header misses $FoundPattern\n";
    $TotalMacrosMissed++;
  }

  seek $file2,0,0;

}

print "Total number of bitfields examined = $TotalMacrosExamined\n";
print "Number of macros obsolete = $TotalMacrosMissed\n";
```